# Search MOSFET for a LENOVO laptop

Tags: mosfet, identification

I have a laptop Lenovo Ideapad S530-13IWL.
It does not turn on anymore.

The faulty component seems to be a MOSFET located at 5 cm of the internal DC-in on the motherboard. When the AC adapter is plugged, this probable MOSFET become immediatly very hot.
When everything is disconnected from the motherboard (screen, fan, battery, SSD, keyboard, etc), it also become very hot immediatly.
The power adapter is delivering the expected 20 volts. Another power adapter lead to the same result.

This is component number P0302 (numbering specific to this motherboard).
The component is marked `6426` on one line, and `BA9K1H` on the next line.
This is a 5x5 mm SMD package with 4 pads on both sides (similar to SO-8, PowerFlat, PowerPAK, etc).
The brand logo is unknown to me. Too small to take a picture with my equipment. The logo is similar to this drawing:
[image]

- I searched the web but found not even a small clue about this component. Does anyone has an idea?
- I'm not used to laptop electronics. What kind of MOSFET can I use as replacement?

Comment: Would it be this perchance: http://www.aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AON6426.pdf.  Searching mosfet 6426 yielded the same result

Comment: The logo you've drawn is clearly that of Alpha & Omega Semiconductor.

Comment: If the mosfet is getting hot, then the problem is most likely elsewhere.